# Parsing Java Server Exception logs

Tags: java, hive, websphere, apache-pig

I have a requirement wherein I have to read all "history" exception logs from a WebSphere server and load them in Hive.
Below is what a typical log looks like but message rows are sometimes extended for 4-5 lines as well. I do not really care about the stack trace but definitely need the Timestamp, ThereadId, Short name, Event Type and full error message in their individual columns.

```
[5/20/16 22:35:39:841 CDT] 00233723 SystemOut     O 22:35:39,840 ERROR [com.xxx.app.yyy.hms.jms.receivers.impl.B2bTonnn278InReceiverImpl] 
xxxRuntimeException{errorVO=com.xxx.app.yyy.nnn.mmm.data.mmmCompleteIntakeErrorVO(diagnosesMessagesExist:false, mmmMessagesExist:false, incrementedKey:null, numPagesWithMessages:1, primaryKeyFields:[], providersMessagesExist:false, requiredFields:[], servicesMessagesExist:true, changeDateTime:05-20-2016 10:35:39:840 PM CDT, changeUserID:SYSTEM, createDateTime:null, createUserID:null, dataSecured:false, dataSecurityTypeList:null, globalMessages:[], historyID:0, messages:{procedureUnitCount=[Field For Label: procedureUnitCount Message ID: 'ERR0010', Message Arguments: '[]']}, trackChanges:false, updateVersion:-1, messages={procedureUnitCount=[Field For Label: procedureUnitCount Message ID: 'ERR0010', Message Arguments: '[]']})}
    at com.xxx.app.yyy.nnn.mmm.businesslogic.impl.mmmImpl.completemmm(mmmImpl.groovy:612)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4988.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I tried doing this by reading one line at a time and parsing using Regex - which failed miserably (only 20% of data met the Regex) and that quality is also poor. I really do not know to proceed here and what delimiter to choose to break that exception string to columns (\t already tried - not working too.)

Any help or pointer to right direction here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Logstash to read and parse the WebSphere logs and post them into Elasticsearch for further processing (i.e use [ELK Stack](https://www.scaleway.com/docs/how-to-use-the-elk-stack-instant-apps/)).

Read related discussion [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-we-monitor-ibm-websphere-event-logs-using-elasticsearch/26543).

With Logstash, you can use [Grok](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) to parse any crappy unstructured log data into something structured and queryable.

Comment: Alright, it appears I will have to create account to use it - and its not free.

Comment: The Elastic Stack — that's Elasticsearch, Logstash, Kibana, and Beats — are open source projects as mentioned officially here - https://www.elastic.co/products. All the 3 are released under Apache license. You can download and install all the 3 softwares directly as described here - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elk-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -A 1  SystemOut LogFile |  awk 'NR%3{printf $0" ";next;}2' | awk '{print $2" "$4" "$8" "$10}'
```